# Radio button validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a calculator in HTML/js, now am trying to add some validation to it but I can't seem to get it to work.

In the below calculator, I added a script that checked if the sex radio button has not been checked then output a message. Unfortunately, when I ran it the message isn't showing anything. Help please

```js
function calcCreatine() {
  var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked').value;;
  var ageInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-age")[0].value;
  var weightInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-weight")[0].value;
  var serumInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-serum")[0].value;
  var result;

  if (sexInput == null) {
    return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";

  } else {

    if (sexInput === 'm') {
      result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput) * weightInput * 1.23) / serumInput);

      result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
      resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
      res = result + resultText.bold();
      return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
    } else {
      result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput) * weightInput * 1.04) / serumInput);

      result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
      resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
      res = result + resultText.bold();
      return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Creatinine clearance calculator. -->
<form id="form-id" method="post">
  <div id="creat-calc">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><strong>Creatinine clearance
                                    calculator</strong></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Sex of patient:</p>
        <div>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="m"> Male
                                    </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="f"> Female
                                    </label>
          <p>Age of patient (years):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-age" />
          <br/><br/>
          <p>Weight of patient (kg):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-weight" />
          <br/><br/>
          <p>Serum creatinine (micromol/L):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-serum" />
          <br/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <div id="crtresult">
          <h5 id="outs"></h5>
          <p>Original Cockcroft-Gault Equation: <a href="https://www.mdcalc.com/creatinine-clearance-cockcroft-gault-equation#creator-insights" style="color:white;"><u> mdcalc website</u></a></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcCreatine();">Calculate
                                </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup.hideCeatCalcFormPopup();">
                                    Close
                                </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resetButton();">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you are not selecting any radio button, following statements returns null:
`document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked')`

since its null this cannot have value property. So I did some modification in the code and stored the whole input instead of the value and then used it later with value property wherever needed.

Here's the solution. Try it yourself:

```js
function calcCreatine() {
  var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked');
  var ageInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-age")[0];
  var weightInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-weight")[0];
  var serumInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-serum")[0];
  var result;

  if (sexInput == null) {
    return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = "Please select your gender";

  } else {

    if (sexInput.value === 'm') {
      result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput.value) * weightInput.value * 1.23) / serumInput.value);

      result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
      resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
      res = result + resultText.bold();
      return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
    } else {
      result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput.value) * weightInput.value * 1.04) / serumInput.value);

      result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
      resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
      res = result + resultText.bold();
      return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Creatinine clearance calculator. -->
<form id="form-id" method="post">
  <div id="creat-calc">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><strong>Creatinine clearance
                                    calculator</strong></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Sex of patient:</p>
        <div>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="m"> Male
                                    </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="f"> Female
                                    </label>
          <p>Age of patient (years):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-age" />
          <br/><br/>
          <p>Weight of patient (kg):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-weight" />
          <br/><br/>
          <p>Serum creatinine (micromol/L):</p>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-serum" />
          <br/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <div id="crtresult">
          <h5 id="outs"></h5>
          <p>Original Cockcroft-Gault Equation: <a href="https://www.mdcalc.com/creatinine-clearance-cockcroft-gault-equation#creator-insights" style="color:white;"><u> mdcalc website</u></a></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calcCreatine();">Calculate
                                </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup.hideCeatCalcFormPopup();">
                                    Close
                                </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resetButton();">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

```
var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked').value;
```

This line is trying to get the value of the selected sex. If the form has just loaded and the user has not selected anything yet, then:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked');
```

Will be `null`, so you will get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

The simplest way to fix that would be to just add a default value to the radio buttons, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="m" checked>
```

That being said, you can also improve the following:

- The `<font>` tag has been removed from HTML5, so it would be a good idea to replace that.
- Since patient sex only affects one line of your code, you can remove the duplicate part by just calculating the result in an `if` statement and doing the rest only once.

I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/dk7qwo3z/13/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is the code is the double ";" in the first line please, change it:

```js
    var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked').value;;
```

to:

```js
    var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked').value;
```

The second problem in you radio button is not working because you are trying to get a value from an element that doesn't exist if you don't **check** the button but if you **check** it and you execute the calculate button then you get an error:

[image]

and this error is because you are trying to obtain a value from an element that doesn't exist yet.

**How to solve it?**

You can modify the first line to get the null value from the element like this:

```js
    var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked');
```

then if the user not **check** the radio button you will get a null value.

Another way could be using the checked property of the element to evaluate if the user checked the button using **true/false** like this:

```
var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]').checked;
```

then in your code you can eval like this:

```
if(sexInput){
    // Do something
}
```

**EDIT**

I added a working exmaple:

**EDIT 2**

Improved the response a little bit more.

```js
function calcCreatine() {
    var sexInput = document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked');
    var ageInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-age")[0].value;
    var weightInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-weight")[0].value;
    var serumInput = document.getElementsByName("patients-serum")[0].value;
    var result;
  
    if (sexInput == null) {
      return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
  
    } else {
  
      if (sexInput === 'm') {
        result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput) * weightInput * 1.23) / serumInput);
  
        result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
        resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
        res = result + resultText.bold();
        return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
      } else {
        result = Math.round(((140 - ageInput) * weightInput * 1.04) / serumInput);
  
        result = result.toString().bold().fontsize(6);
        resultText = " mL/min".small() + " - Creatinine clearance.";
        res = result + resultText.bold();
        return document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = res;
      }
  
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="asd.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Creatinine clearance calculator. -->
    <form id="form-id" method="post">
      <div id="creat-calc">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
              <strong>Creatinine clearance calculator</strong>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Sex of patient:</p>
            <div>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="m" /> Male
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="f" /> Female
              </label>
              <p>Age of patient (years):</p>
              <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-age" />
              <br /><br />
              <p>Weight of patient (kg):</p>
              <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-weight" />
              <br /><br />
              <p>Serum creatinine (micromol/L):</p>
              <input type="number" min="1" max="120" name="patients-serum" />
              <br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <div id="crtresult">
              <h5 id="outs"></h5>
              <p>
                Original Cockcroft-Gault Equation:
                <a
                  href="https://www.mdcalc.com/creatinine-clearance-cockcroft-gault-equation#creator-insights"
                  style="color: white"
                  ><u> mdcalc website</u></a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              onclick="calcCreatine();"
            >
              Calculate
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-danger"
              onclick="popup.hideCeatCalcFormPopup();"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button
              type="reset"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              onclick="resetButton();"
            >
              Reset
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan that makes a lot of sense